# This Riley should make us better people

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme, knowledge

My Prefix should come in moderation.

My Infix rule the nation.

My Suffix communicates after germination.

HINT 1:

> The Prefix is often used to help learn new things.

HINT 2:

> Hint 1 could be made into a bigger hint by adding the word "animals" between two of the words...

Comment: I think you may have a grammatical error in the second line (My Infix "rules' the nation) :D

Comment: @KevinL not if the infix is plural. I mean, technically you're correct it would be 'rules' even if the infix refers to a plural, but this could be a hint. Or.. it's a typo :)

Comment: Nah, this can't be a hint. This is more likely to just be a typo (I think) :D

Comment: It is plural ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I’m not sure I’m extremely comfortable with my interpretations, but are you

> TREATMENT?

My Prefix should come in moderation.

> Thanks to @Cashbee for finding TREAT. Go upvote their answer!! :)

My Infix rule the nation.

> This is a plural as alluded to by OP....and my sketchy part of the solution...by saying that MEN rule the nation? (Which isn’t entirely true.)

My Suffix communicates after germination.

> This refers to an ENT (singular, because he communicates, not they communicate), because they’re talking trees from Lord of the Rings.

Title:

> I suppose treatment/good treatment all around could make us better people, yes...

Comment: Smashed it! And yeah you got the reasons why, even MEN, because they are disproportionately in charge of things, but lets try to not get too political :P

Comment: Thanks, @AHKieran! Steering very clear of the politics for sure. Great puzzle! :)

Answer (score 2):

Fun answer: Are you ...

> Corduroy?

My Prefix should come in moderation.

> CORD - Literally anything is unhealthy in too much dosis, even cords. A ton of cords will still crush you. lol pretty far fetched but hey

My Infix rule the nation.

> UROY - U Roy has a song called "Rule the Nation"

I know that..

> I generously misread "Infix" for "Suffix" and left out the actual suffix clue. This answer is mostly about the partial rule the nation clue, wrapped in a not-so-serious answer. I just wanted to show that maybe "rule the nation" is *not* a typo! (@KevinL :D)

Comment: Very creative indeed (+1) :D

Comment: Not correct but thank you for seeing the wording as pluralisation and not a typo ;)

Answer (score 2):

Partial: Prefix

> TREAT. Treats are used to train animals do tricks (it helps them learn new things), but should definitely be given to them in moderation, else they have no effect.

Comment: Well done, now for the rest :D +1

Answer (score 1):

Wild guess (and probably a stretch) but:

> compress

My Prefix should come in moderation:

> "Com," as in ".com"... Time spent on the internet should be used in moderation.  However (hint), the internet is a wonderful place to learn things.

My Infix rule the nation

> "Pre," short for President. (Could also be "Pres" but then the last clue doesn't work.)

My Suffix communicates after germination.

> My biggest stretch, but "ss" could be "seed and soil" as the seed and soil "communicate" during the germination process?

Comment: I'm afraid not but good try!

Comment: I figured, thanks!  Good riddle, I'm looking forward to seeing the answer!

Comment: I added another hint which may help you to have another go :)